# JQuery: Get the parent element id of a clicked element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, parent

I have a div like this:

```
<div id="popupDiv1" class="popupDivClass">
    <a id="popupDivClose" class="popupCloseClass">x</a>
</div>
```

When I click on the 'x' (I want to run a jquery function called `disablePopup(id);` where id is the id of the coresponding popupDiv (I have many popupDiv each with it's own X button.

in order to do so I implemented the following

```
$(".popupCloseClass").click(function (event) {
    var buttonID = $(event.target).attr("id");
    var id = $( buttonID).closest("div").attr("id");
disablePopup(id);
});
```

basicaly I get the id of the popupCloseClass clicked then I get the id of it's parent (the corresponding popupDiv) via the closest method. then I call disablePopup.

But this is not working.

I even tryed to use the `var buttonID = $(buttonID).parent().attr("id");` method but did not work either.

I also tried `var id = this.id;`

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: `buttonID` will contain the string `"popupDivClose"`. If you pass this to jQuery, it will search for all elements with the **tag name**  `popupDivClose`. The ID selectors starts with a `#`. But since `event.target` (or even `this`) already point to the element you want, simply use `$(event.target).closest(...)...` or `$(this).closest(...)...`. I recommend to read some more jQuery tutorials...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

instead of using `closest` you can use `parent` like this...

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");
```

Notice you can use the `this` keyword to reference the element that kicked off the event. As you have it, you are using the value of `buttonID` as the element selector which would have a value of `"popupDivClose"` and without adding a `#` at the start it will not search for an ID, but rather a tag element called "popupDivClose".

If you wanted to keep using buttonID you could have used this line of code to get it working...

```
var id = $("#" + buttonID).parent().attr("id");
```

However, I would have preferred to write the whole event like so...

```
$(".popupCloseClass").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id");

    disablePopup(id);
});
```

notice the use of `event.preventDefault();` this will ensure that the browser will not process the natural action for a link click (i.e. page navigation) - though, in Chrome at least, you need to specify a href value for the navigation anyway

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/UJQXs/)

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
$(".popupCloseClass").click(function (event) {
    var id = $(this).closest("div").attr("id");
});
```

(you could also use `$(this).parent().attr("id");` ) but using closest is safer in case you change your html structure

Comment: Note that `parent()` will only return the immediate parent and therefore the selector parameter is pointless. you can however use `parents(selector)` which will take a selector and return all parents (all the way up the tree) that match the selector

Comment: @musefan yes it pointless, in my experience it's better to use closest() because you usually end up modifying your html and breaking the code that uses parent()

Comment: A good point to make, definitely something for consideration. However, I am yet to have broken my code this way... then again, I don't use this kind of functionality too often anyway

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
$('a.popupCloseClass').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
});​
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/yeJmJ/)**

You should just use `this` instead of the way you are getting the ID and then trying to use it as a selector (you were missing the `#` before the ID):

Answer (score 0):

This must work:

```
$(".popupCloseClass").click(function (event) 
{
    var buttonID = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    disablePopup(buttonID);
});
```